# create GPO on computers OU

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016

I want to apply a GPO only on the computers OU (and not the domain controllers)
How can I achieve it on windows 2016 ? 
Looks like I need to pick in the security filter each computer by name. 
I want to disable browser master on any machine that is not domain controller through GPO. 
What is the steps to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: you right click on the OU and click on either `link existing gpo` or `create and link gpo`

Comment: You *did* create a "computers" and move your computer objects there?

Answer (score 1):

The computers OU isn't technically an OU, it's a Container. As such, you can't link a GPO to this Container. You can create an OU and move the relevant computer objects to this OU and then create/link a GPO to this OU... Or... you can create/link a GPO at the Domain level and use Security Filtering in your GPO to make it apply to only specific computer objects.

Comment: thanks I'll try to create this OU - it was very convenient that I've already had the group of all non DC ready....

Comment: You can redirect new computers in your own shiny OU: `redircmp ou=myshinycomputers,DC=company,dc=com`